# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que aparezca esta parte de mi código? (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

Lo que pasa es que una parte de mi código es un producto entre dos matrices (lo que esta en asteriscos) se dirige automáticamente al menú principal, y la causa de esto es por un while(true), que lo regresa, y pues, no hallo la forma para que pueda aparecer sin que me regrese al menú principal.

```
while(true)
    
    clc;
    O=input('Ingrese 2 si desea entrar el menú:');
    if O==2
        
        
        disp('1. Fundamentos de Geometría')
        disp('2. Triángulos y Cuadriláteros')
        disp('3. Geometría Analítica Vectorial')
        disp('4. Geometría de Movimiento')
        opc=input('Seleccione la unidad que desea\n');
    end
            switch opc
        
            %Fundamentos de Geometría
            case 1
                clc;

                disp('1. Sistema de Coordenadas');
                disp('2. Ángulos');
                disp('3. Regresar');
                upc=input('Seleccione un tema: ');
                
                switch upc
                 
                    case 1
                        clc;

                        disp('1. Primer ejercicio');
                        disp('2. Segundo ejercicio');
                        disp('3. Tercer ejercicio');
                        disp('4. Cuarto ejercicio');
                        disp('5. Regresar');
                        es=input('Seleccione un ejercicio:');

                        switch es
                        
                            case 1
                                



                        end
                    
                    case 2
                        clc;

                        disp('1. Primer ejercicio');
                        disp('2. Segundo ejercicio');
                        disp('3. Tercer ejercicio');
                        disp('4. Regresar');
                        ea=input('Seleccione un ejercicio:');

                        switch ea
                        

                        end




                end
            
            %Triángulos y Cuadriláteros
            case 2
                clc;

                disp('1. Semejanza de Triángulos');
                disp('2. Área y perímetro de triángulos y cuadrilateros');
                disp('3. Relaciones métricas en tríangulos rectángulos');
                disp('4. Regresar');
                ipc=input('Seleccione un tema:');

                switch ipc

                    case 1
                        clc;

                        disp('1. Primer ejercicio');
                        disp('2. Segundo ejercicio');
                        disp('3. Tercer ejercicio');
                        disp('4. Regresar');
                        e1=input('Seleccione un ejercicio:');
                    
                    case 2
                        clc;

                        disp('1. Primer ejercicio')
                        disp('2. Segundo ejercicio');
                        disp('3. Regresar');
                        e2=input('Seleccione un ejercicio:');

                    case 3
                        clc;

                        disp('1. Primer ejercicio');
                        disp('2. Segundo ejercicio');
                        disp('3. Regresar');
                        e3=input('Seleccione un ejercicio:');

                end
            
            %Geometría analítica vectorial
            case 3
                clc;
               
            
            
                                    
        
         
         
            
            %Geometría de Movimiento
            case 4
                clc;
                disp('1. Composición de transformaciones');
                disp('2. Regresar');
                u4=input('Seleccione un tema:');
                
                    switch u4
                        case 1
                            clc;
                            disp('a. Obtener la imagen del triángulo con vértice en los puntos A, B, C al vector:');
                            disp('1. 90° alrededor del origen');
                            disp('2. 45° alrededor del origen');
                            disp('3. 180° alrededor del origen');
                            abc=input('Elija un angulo: ');
                                
                            switch abc
                                case 1
                                    
                                    F=input('Ingrese el primer punto(x) para el vértice A:');
                                    T=input('Ingrese el segundo punto(y) para el vértice A:');
                                    E=input('Ingrese el primer punto(x) para el vértice B:');
                                    G=input('Ingrese el segundo punto(y) para el vértice B:');
                                    D=input('Ingrese el primer punto(x) para el vértice C:');
                                    U=input('Ingrese el segundo punto(y) para el vértice C:');
                                    
                                   A=[F, T, 1; E, G, 1; D, U, 1];
                                   B=[0, 1, 0; 1, 0, 0; 0, 0, 1];
                                   **variable=A*B;
                                   disp(variable);**
                                   

                                     
                                case 2
                                    
                                    F=input('Ingrese el primer punto(x) para el vértice A:');
                                    T=input('Ingrese el segundo punto(y) para el vértice A:');
                                    E=input('Ingrese el primer punto(x) para el vértice B:');
                                    G=input('Ingrese el segundo punto(y) para el vértice B:');
                                    D=input('Ingrese el primer punto(x) para el vértice C:');
                                    U=input('Ingrese el segundo punto(y) para el vértice C:');
                                      
                                     A=[F, T, 1; E, G, 1; D, U, 1];
                                     L=[sqrt(2)/2, sqrt(2)/2, 0; sqrt(2)/2, sqrt(2)/2, 0; 0, 0, 1];
                                     **disp(A*L);**
                                 
                                case 3
                                    
                                    F=input('Ingrese el primer punto(x) para el vértice A:');
                                    T=input('Ingrese el segundo punto(y) para el vértice A:');
                                    E=input('Ingrese el primer punto(x) para el vértice B:');
                                    G=input('Ingrese el segundo punto(y) para el vértice B:');
                                    D=input('Ingrese el primer punto(x) para el vértice C:');
                                    U=input('Ingrese el segundo punto(y) para el vértice C:');
                                      
                                    A=[F, T, 1; E, G, 1; D, U, 1];
                                    J=[-1, 0, 0; 0, -1, 0; 0, 0, 1];
                                    **disp(A*J);**
                                
                            end
                                    
                    end

        
        
        
  
            end
     


    
   
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes añadir un waitforbuttonpress para que se quede el resultado en pantalla hasta que pulses un boton y comience de nuevo el bucle.